# Grunt jshint reporter to send out emails

Tags: gruntjs, jshint, nodemailer

I have added grunt jshint task to my grunt. I created custom reporter to send out jsHint output as email. My custom reporter function is invoked. But no emails are coming through. There are no errors in the code.

Grunt version: "grunt": "^0.4.5",
"nodemailer": "^1.11.0",
"nodemailer-sendmail-transport": "^1.0.0"

Here is the sample code:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport  = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
var async = require('async');
module.exports = {
        reporter: function (errors) {
            var len = errors.length,
                str = '';
            var items = [1];

            errors.forEach(function (r) {
                var file = r.file,
                    err = r.error;

                str += file + ": line " + err.line + ", col " +
                    err.character + ", " + err.reason + "\n";
            });

            if (str) {
                str += "\n" + len + " error" + ((len === 1) ? "" : "s") + "\n";
            }                    

            var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport( smtpTransport( {
                service: "gmail",
                secureConnection: false, // use SSL
                port: 587, // port for secure SMTP
                auth: {
                    user: "<my gmail username>",
                    pass: "<gmail account password>"
                },
                tls:{
                    ciphers:'SSLv3'
                },
                logger: true, // log to console
                debug: true // include SMTP traffic in the logs
            }));


            // setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
            var mailOptions = {
                from: '<sender address>', 
                to: '<recipient address>', 
                subject: 'Hello', // Subject line
                text: "why are you not working"
               /* text: str */// plaintext body
                /*html: '<b>Hello world</b>' // html body*/
            };

            async.eachSeries(items, function (item, next) {
                transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
                    // THIS CALLBACK IS NOT CALLED AT ALL
                    if(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    }else{
                        console.log("Message sent");
                    }
                    next(null);  
                });
            }, function(err){
                // All tasks are done now
                console.log('All tasks are done now');
            });                
        }
    };
```

with async or without async doesn't matter. No emails are coming. I tried bye turning on the "Receive emails from unsecured apps" by following another stackoverflow post. That also did not help.

I would like to know is this correct approach or not? Any help/input is appreicated.

Comment: did you follow the [setup](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer#setting-up) of nodemailer

Comment: @Zamboney: Yes, I did.

Comment: I tried downgrading nodemailer to 0.7.1 too. But no help. I would highly appreciate if somebody points me in right direction.

Comment: Try removing var smtpTransport  = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');